# Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming (15IRH) Windows 11 does not boot after disk clone

Tags: ssd, windows-11, bsod, nvme, disk-cloning

I am an ordinary Linux guy trying to upgrade my friend's laptop Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming (15IRH).

The original disk NVMe 3.0 x4 Intel SSDPEKNW512G8L 512GB cloned using an image of the disk on an external drive onto NVMe 3.0 x4 Samsung 980 1TB (MZ-V8V1T0BW) using Linux `pv` tool, Windows 11 Home does not boot with INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error. (This process is the same as a direct copy.)

Of course, I booted live Linux (Mint), installed `pv` on it, and did the job done. Twice that is, once doing the image of the original NVMe disk, and second pushing this data onto the new disk.

Note: The disk IS seen in the BIOS/UEFI boot menu as Windows Boot Manager with the new disk name in brackets.

What I tried:

- Made sure all but the tiny Microsoft reserved partition are mountable in R/W mode within Linux and the data is there. Yes, EFI partition too.
- Reset BIOS to defaults, AHCI stayed, Secure Boot off stayed, pure-UEFI stayed as well.
- I switched then to the old disk, which still luckily boots, made sure disk encryption is off, which is a matter of course due to #1, those partitions would not be mountable otherwise, hey...

Maybe I tried something else too, but now too tired to realize it.

I literally ran out of ideas by now. What can I do?

If there are any comments to fill in any details, in the morning I will do them.

---

I noticed something strange on `fdisk` of the new disk. There are strange values of minimum/optimal I/O size I haven't seen thus far:

Samsung SSD 980 1TB:

```
root@mint:~# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 980 1TB                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 131072 bytes
```

By contrast with my Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB            
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

---

I wish more luck to future readers, leaving this question in place for them.